# adding images next to radio buttons in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, radio-button

How can i create radio buttons in cakephp and attach an image to every button? is that even possible, i am creating a list of dynamic radio buttons using

```
echo $this->Form->input('db.field', array('type' => 'radio', 'options' => $myOptions,  'label' => 'myLabel')); ?>
```

any help please? thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply put the image in the options array:

```
$myOptions          = array();
$myOptions['power'] = $this->Html->image('cake.power.gif');
$myOptions['icon']  = $this->Html->image('cake.icon.png');

echo $this->Form->input('db.field', array('type' => 'radio', 'options' => $myOptions,  'label' => 'myLabel')); ?>
```

Comment: and where to put the values ?

Comment: @endo.anaconda The values are the keys of the `$myOptions` array